# use empty() or just use > in php which is the fastest way

Tags: php, optimization

I am trying to check the value of a variable if it is not NULL nor 0 to show its value

```
$saleprice =  $product["product_details"][0]->salePrice;
```

I know that using

```
if(!empty($saleprice) ) echo " on sale , sale price : $saleprice  ";
```

or

```
if((int)$saleprice > 0) echo " on sale , sale price : $saleprice  ";
```

will give me the same result, but which one is the fastest ?

thank you in advance

Comment: if *$product["product_details"][0]->salePrice* really return NULL then you can just use *if($saleprice)*

Comment: Does it matter which is fastest? I'd go with whatever is more readable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize

Comment: None of the approaches listed are functions, and none of them are comparable. You're also forgetting `===` and `==!` (type and value checks). Also: micro-optimization is the root of all evil. just [know what the pitfalls are](http://kunststube.net/isset/), and you're fine

Comment: @Nassim: You want `$saleprice` to be != 0 or `NULL`, ie: you need it to be a _truthy_ value, in which case: `if ($saleprice) {` is all you need anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that out yourself using php's [microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) function:

```
$saleprice = 1;

$start = microtime(true);
if(!empty($saleprice)) echo $saleprice . '<br/>';
echo 'empty: ' . number_format(( microtime(true) - $start), 30) . '<br/>';

$start = microtime(true);
if(!is_null($saleprice))  echo $saleprice . '<br/>';
echo 'is_null: ' . number_format(( microtime(true) - $start), 30) . '<br/>';

$start = microtime(true);
if((int)$saleprice > 0)  echo $saleprice . '<br/>';
echo 'int cast:' . number_format(( microtime(true) - $start), 30) . '<br/>';
```

On my local machine this outputs the following:

> empty: 0.000012159347534179687500000000
>   is_null: 0.000011920928955078125000000000
>   int cast:0.000010967254638671875000000000

Meaning in case `$saleprice` contains an integer, the int cast is the fastest. If it contains `null`, I get the following output:

> empty: 0.000019073486328125000000000000
>   is_null: 0.000029087066650390625000000000
>   int cast:0.000034093856811523437500000000

After playing around a bit more, I think it's safe to say that it's highly dependent on what the variable you're checking actually contains. So unfortunately there's not one answer saying which is the fastest.

---

***Update***

Not using any operator or language construct seems to yield the best performance:

```
$price = null;

$start = microtime(true);
if($price) echo $price . '<br>';
$end = microtime(true);

printf('null: %f' . PHP_EOL, $end - $start);

$price = (int) $price;

$start = microtime(true);
if($price) echo $price . '<br>';
$end = microtime(true);

printf('0: %f' . PHP_EOL, $end - $start);

++$price;

$start = microtime(true);
if ($price) echo $price . '<br>';
$end = microtime(true);

printf('1: %f' . PHP_EOL, $end - $start);
```

The results are:

> null: 0.000004
>   0: 0.000001
>   1: 0.000010

Comment: @Nassim: you want to check if `$saleprice` is neither `null` nor `0`. Both these values evaluate to `false`, so why use operators or language constructs at all: `if ($saleprice)` will do, and it seems to outperform anything else: `null: 0.000004
(int) 0: 0.000001
(int) 1: 0.000010` with code `if ($saleprice) echo $saleprice . '<br>';` timed

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem thanks , I will update the answer and hopefully treegarden will accept my update

Comment: @Nassim: Changed your edit. It's best to leave the original answer as-is, and just add more info below